# is_dir() fails while scanning a directory in php

Tags: php, file-type, scandir

I'm trying to build a `<ul>` list with a `<li>` for each directory in a main folder.
here's my code :

```
<?php

$dir = opendir(getEnv("DOCUMENT_ROOT") . "/folder");

while(($file = readdir($dir)) !== false ){
  if( is_dir($file) && $file !== "." && $file !== ".." ){
    echo "<li>" . $file . "</li>";
  }
}

closedir($dir);

?>
```

there are two directories in /home/example/folder but there are not recognized as folders (for sure they are !)

if I "`echo`" the files in the while loop they are printed (they well exist for the script no trouble on that side).
If I try to "`filetype`" them, a `lstat failed` error is thrown, I searched on internet the meaning of it and I end up with nothing but technically support that I pain to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that inside "folder" directory you can have two directories (a and b),then the reading retrieve "a" and "b" as file names, while is_dir receive a full path filename or a relative filename, you have two options:

1. pass the full path to filename to the is_dir function (see example code).
2. pass the relative path (depends on where you put your script).

```php
if( is_dir($dir . "/" . $file) && $file !== "." && $file !== ".." ){ ......
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
while($file = readdir($dir)) {
   if (...) { }
}
```

The `!== false` portion is not required. if readdir reaches the end, it returns a false, and the loop will automatically terminate. Your version is being parsed as:

```
$file gets the value of (readdir($file) is not false)
```

e.g. you're assigning the boolean result of `readdir($file) !== false`, not the return value from readdir.

---

to expand on my comment below, regarding [operator precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

PHP's parse tree of your loop setup looks like this, expanded:

```
$bool = (readdir($dir) !== false);
$file = $bool;
```

To fix this, either remove the !== false portion entirely, or enforce your own precedence with extra brackets:

```
($file = readdir($dir)) !== false
```

Comment: i don't see anything wrong with my condition, the assignment is processed before the value of $file to be compared to `!== false`. anyway `!== false` is just way to be more verbose with the code. And this is not resolving my trouble. Why are you posting this as an answer ?

Comment: Read this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php    `=` has a lower precedence than `===` and `!==` in PHP, so your !== comparison is being done FIRST.

Comment: I already know that, the extra brackets are present in my code don't you see them ?

Comment: Well, d'oh... sorry, you're right. I'll just go into that corner over there and rub my eyes with a wire brush.